# Strange behavior using Lodash and Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash, type-inference

I can't understand why booleans is of type boolean[] ...

```
    const obj: { [key: number]: string } = { 1: "Hi", 2: ", there" };
    const booleans = _.chain(obj)
        .keys()
        .map((key: number) => ({ ItemKey: key, ItemText: obj[key] }))
        .value();
```

Any clue?! The following code produces a variable with the correct type of { ItemKey: number, ItemText: string }[]:

```
    const obj: { [key: number]: string } = { 1: "Hi", 2: ", there" };
    const correctType = _.chain(obj)
        .keys()
        .map(key => ({ ItemKey: parseInt(key), ItemText: obj[parseInt(key)] })) // key is inferred to be string, because keys() returns string[]
        .value();
```

I'm using Typescript 2.0.10 for compilation, but even VS Code with Typescript 2.2.2 says the same thing with the intellisense.

Comment: Probably an issue with the lodash typings. If you change your key to `string`:  `map((key: string) => ({ ItemKey: key, ItemText: obj[key] }))`, the types are inferred correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the lodash typings. I would submit a pull request!

See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c2bca7c/types/lodash/index.d.ts#L8563